# Bulk Delete of In App Purchase (IAP) products on iTunes Connect

Tags: in-app-purchase, itunes, bulk

Is there a simple way to delete a large number of in app purchase products from iTunes in bulk?  We have a few hundred products and have made changes replacing them with new ones and it seems very tedious to delete each on individually through the iTunes UI.

Answer (score -1):

I have even hart times to delete one...

---

Sorry I found the button... Its on the top left of the detail IAP detail view.